# Formatting elements of a list into a specific string

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to take a list of terms and output them in a specific format.

For example, I have a list of verbs:

```
verbs = ['eat', 'run', 'jump', 'play', 'walk', 'talk', 'send']
```

and I want my output to be a string, where each item in the list is also a string, delineated by a `|`

```
magic(verbs)
```

output:

```
"eat" | "run" | "jump" | etc.
```

I've tried using the `.join` method, but that just gives me one big string of the terms separated by pipes, instead of what I want. Any ideas? I'm pretty new to Python and I'm sorry if this is incredibly low-brow or something that has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: Use a list comprehension that puts the quotes around each item, then use `.join()` to join them with a pipe.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
verbs = ['eat', 'run', 'jump', 'play', 'walk', 'talk', 'send']
x=(' | '.join('"' + item + '"' for item in verbs))
print(x)
```

you can see ouput [here](http://ideone.com/K8nuyN)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
verbs = ['eat', 'run', 'jump', 'play', 'walk', 'talk', 'send']
print("|".join(['"'+e+'"' for e in verbs]))
```

Output:

```
"eat"|"run"|"jump"|"play"|"walk"|"talk"|"send"
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want:

```
def magic(terms):
    print(' | '.join('"%s"' % term for term in terms))

verbs = ['eat', 'run', 'jump', 'play', 'walk', 'talk', 'send']
magic(verbs)  # -> "eat" | "run" | "jump" | "play" | "walk" | "talk" | "send"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
verbs = ['eat', 'run', 'jump', 'play', 'walk', 'talk', 'send']

def magic(s):
    return ' | '.join('"%s"' % x for x in s)

print(magic(verbs))
# "eat" | "run" | "jump" | "play" | "walk" | "talk" | "send"
```

Answer (score 0):

Between each quote-enclosed verb, put a pipe:

```
" | ".join('"{0}"'.format(verb) for verb in verbs)
```

```
>>> verbs = ['eat', 'run', 'jump', 'play', 'walk', 'talk', 'send']
>>> print(" | ".join('"{0}"'.format(verb) for verb in verbs))
"eat" | "run" | "jump" | "play" | "walk" | "talk" | "send"
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote so I can improve the answer. Blind downvotes just seem spiteful. :)